# Jekyll liquid variables as inline CSS values

Tags: css, jekyll, liquid

Is passing liquid variables as inline styles commonly frowned upon? Here is an example of my markup:

```
 <div class="span-8-12">
    <h6> {{page.role}}</h6>
    <h1 style="color:{{ page.accentColor }};"> {{page.title}} </h1>
 </div> 
 <article class="intro">
    <p style="color:{{ page.txtColor }};"> {{ page.summary }} </p>
 </article>
```

I am setting h1 and p colors using the liquid variables in my posts. I know I could pass the variable directly to a CSS file, but then'd i'd have to write even more markup and CSS. Is this method valid or is there a better method on systematically changing values of color based off page variables?

Answer (score 3):

Better would be to set a class, rather than directly setting the styles inline.

```
<div class=" {{ page.typeOfClass  }}">
    <div class="span-8-12">
        <h6> {{page.role}}</h6>
        <h1 > {{page.title}} </h1>
     </div> 
     <article class="intro">
        <p > {{ page.summary }} </p>
     </article>
</div>
```

Then in your `whatever.css` set the styles for the different classes you want:

```
.someClass h1{
    color:blue;
}
.someClass .intro p{
    color:red;
}
```

for example.

Comment: Why would you say use a class instead of use it directly on the tag? Would it be more of a case by case situation in where to use them?