# Jekyll: the use liquid tag inside inline css

Tags: jekyll

Recently I got the chance to learn Jekyll, and found how amazing and powerful Jekyll is. Liquid tag is easy and convenience to use with so far one restriction. Anyway, I use Visual Studio Code and it complains about using the liquid tag inside inline css, so I start to think either this is not the right practice to use liquid tag? Where should we not use liquid tag and why?

I did searching and came to conclusion that this is a common practice to use liquid tag inside inline css;

[Jekyll liquid variables as inline CSS values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681926/jekyll-liquid-variables-as-inline-css-values)

**Note** 
By the way, the code compiles and runs but visual studio code complains about the liquid tag `{{ }}` inside the style attribute `style=""`.

**Add images**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] or a link to a repo and site?

Comment: If you don't show *how* you use your liquid tags inside your inline CSS, it is hard to tell why it doesn't work for you. In other words, give us your code or at least a [MCVE], as @Kevin already said.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Post it as text, and post enough of it so we can actually understand what you're doing. A screenshot of a single line of code is not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: I was thinking it is  more of general question to the best practice than specific error, but if the inline css error explains will be helpful. Again thanks for commenting and have a look on this.

Comment: Also, please try to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). Come up with a [mcve] instead of posting a complicated example that contains a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: @KevinWorkman just that single line complains, but the code compiles and it runs. Whenever I use liquid tag inside the style attribute, `visual studio code` complains and disregard what I put in there. I try to fix code that shows error or warning asap, unless it is unavoidable.

Comment: @Kim.LBy How that line behaves depends on whether the file has frontmatter in it or not. I also see that the file name starts with an underscore. Doesn't that mean that Jekyll won't touch it? This is why we need a more specific example that we can actually test.

Comment: Oh I see, I was focusing on the line itself. I am still familiar myself with `frontmatter`, but not know it enough to know it can make a different. Anyway, I just want to follow the template and use the `_`, but it is still under the `include` so I can pull the content in the `components/_contact.html` by using `{% include components/_contact.html id="john" %}` in the `_layouts/page.html`